# jQuery Mobile and a fixed footer

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've got a jQuery mobile app wrapped in PhoneGap. I'm trying to use a fixed footer and header and having some trouble with the footer.
If I have content with X length and then after a click the content is smaller - the footer would move up and not stick to the bottom of the screen. If I click on the screen it will go back to its place.

Any ideas why this happens?

My footer code is:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer_main">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" class="search">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bycity" data-icon="search" class="search2">City</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

This issue would happen on Android and iPhone in pretty much the same way (iPhone maybe even more).

BTW - I'm using jQuery mobile "jquery.mobile-1.0b2" and PhoneGap 1.0

Comment: It's a jquery mobile issue. No solution at the moment.

Comment: wait b3, ... and the final version

Comment: It's still an open issue even in 1.0RC2

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your footer:

```
<div class=”footer” data-role="footer" .....>
```

And add the following function to your click event:

```
$('.footer').trigger('create');
```

Should look something like this:

```
$('.class').click(function() {

    $('.footer').trigger('create');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. My Navigation is hidden, and will be shown, when user clicks show-navigation-button.

The problem is, that JQM calculates and animates for the footer position the top attribute instad of using position: fixed; bottom: 0;

Im sure, that there is reason for their choice. But i dont't know what it is.
And i found no function for repositioning the footer top-pos. 
`$('.footer').trigger('create')`;
..is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can have footers fixed at the bottom by adding CSS properties to it.

```
bottom:0;
position:absolute !important; 
top: auto !important; 
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

add style="position: absolute" to footer div like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="position: absolute">
```